# select the names from multiple tables and sort with the same id

Tags: c#, json, sql-server-2008

I have a problem. I have 2 tables which look like this:

Table1: **Country**

```
Name: Germany
ID: 1

Name: France
ID: 2
```

Table2: **Cities**

```
Name: Frankfurt
ID: 1

Name: Paris
ID: 2
```

I want to write a select statement where it compare the id's and sorts the cities with the correct countries with the same id. The output should be in a json format.

My code look like this so far:

```
public class StadtHelper
{
   public class STADT
   {
       public string StadtName { get; set; }
       public string RegionID { get; set; }
   }

   internal static List<STADT> Stadt()
   {
       List<STADT> stadtObject = new List<STADT>();

       using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BOOK-IT-V2;Integrated Security=true;"))
       using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT NAME, REGION_ID FROM STADT",con))
       {
           con.Open();
           using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
           {
               while (rdr.Read())
               {
                   if (rdr["NAME"] != DBNull.Value && rdr["REGION_ID"] != DBNull.Value)
                   {
                       stadtObject.Add(new STADT()
                       {
                           StadtName = rdr["NAME"].ToString(),
                           RegionID = rdr["REGION_ID"].ToString()
                       });
                   }
               }
           }
       }

       return stadtObject;
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance

i edited my code:

```
    public class StadtHelper
{
    public class STADT
    {
        public string StadtName { get; set; }
        public string RegionName { get; set; }
    }
    internal static List<STADT> Stadt()
    {
        List<STADT> stadtObject = new List<STADT>();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BOOK-IT-V2;Integrated Security=true;"))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT REGION.NAME, STADT.NAME FROM REGION, STADT WHERE REGION.ID = STADT.REGION_ID ORDER BY REGION.NAME" , con))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    if (rdr["REGION.NAME"] != DBNull.Value && rdr["STADT.NAME"] != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        stadtObject.Add(new STADT()
                        {
                            RegionName = rdr["REGION.NAME"].ToString(),
                            StadtName = rdr["STADT"].ToString()
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return stadtObject;
    }
}
```

there is still a bug, my web service gives me an exeption:

```
 System.IndexOutOfRangeException: REGION.NAME
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal(String fieldName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_Item(String name)
   at StadtHelper.Stadt() in C:\Users\Yeah\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WebService1\WebService1\StadtHelper.cs:line 31
   at WebService1.Service1.Stadt() in C:\Users\Yeah\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WebService1\WebService1\Service1.asmx.cs:line 77
```

Comment: And what's the problem? What output *are* you getting now, and what do you need to get instead?

Comment: i need a select statement which sorts the 2 different tables by the same id. and after that i need a json output which displays me the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your tables, the TSQL would look like,

```
    select ci.Name, co.Name
      from Cities  ci
inner join Country co on co.ID = ci.ID
  order by ci.Name, co.Name
```

Comment: i edited my post,  but i get an error. could you please help me?

Comment: Give this a try: SELECT r.NAME, s.NAME FROM REGION r LEFT OUTER JOIN STADT s ON s.ID = r.ID ORDER BY REGION.NAME

Comment: i tried this but now i can see only the countries the cities are NULL

Comment: It sounds like your ID values are not matching. Make sure that they do not have spaces in them.